# How to populate IList<t> from DataTable or from a table in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table say, Student.
I have a class 'Student'. 
I want to populate `IList<Student>` with objects of Student class from Student table in database.

Is it possible to implement this?

If yes then how to implement this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this:

[Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx)

Comment: I have the concept of populating Dataset using SqlDataAdapter but what I need is to populate IList<> Selecting data from Student Table. I have properties in Student class having same name as of Student table in sql server Database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [strongly typed Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163877.aspx) for this. So you dont need to implement classes for your data access layer, because they will be generated automatically.

When you need a generic List of its type, you could extend the [partial auto-generated Dataadapter-Class](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/using-partial-classes-to-make-intelligent-datasets/)(not in the designer.cs from the Dataset but in its codebehind) with such a function.